# Updating a field on the lookup object using a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a lookup to a custom object called Project on my Opportunity object. I am trying to write a trigger that updates an Active, Awarded, and Title on the Project object whenever the Active, Awarded, or Title field is updated on Opportunity based some on more logic that isn't in my code below. This is my first trigger and needing a little help due to a NullPointerException where I try to set **Project__r.Active__c = true**. Any thoughts?

```
    trigger ProjectFieldsTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {


    //List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT Name, Active__c, Funded__c, Title__c, Project__r.Name, Project__r.Active__c, Project__r.Awarded__c 
    //  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New];

    for(Opportunity o: Trigger.New){

        if(o.Project__c != null){

            if(o.Active__c == 'Y'){
                o.Project__r.Active__c = true;
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow get a list of the related objects, then perform a DML statement on them. At the most basic level, you could do this:

```
Map<Id, Project__c> projects = new Map<Id, Project__c>();
for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Active__c == 'y' && record.Project__c != null) {
        projects.put(record.Project__c, new Project__c(Id=record.Project__c, Active__c=true));
    }
}
update projects.values();
```

An alternative solution would be to query for inactive projects that are linked to those active opportunities, and just update those. This trades a DML statement for a query statement, though, so you'll want to determine which is more important.

Finally, you can build this same logic with Process Builder, which means you really don't need to write code at all. The choice is up to you, but I'd recommend you just give the Process Builder a try.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I have another logic question: Lets say there are already Opportunities in the related list, how do you then pull that entire related list and then iterate through it to check values?

Comment: @Alex Do you mean just from one project, or any number of projects? There's a few ways you might go about doing this, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: From one project. Lets say I have opportunity 1,2, and 3. I need to check that if they are all not active, the project will not be active.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the fields in lookup relationship are not auto-populated in before trigger. They are null if you don't use a SOQL query to retrieve them. Also, since o.Project__r is null is this case, you will be getting a null pointer exception when trying to retrieve o.Project__r.Active__c.

Since sfdcfox has already poped up with the DML solution. I will put the SOQL solution here, which I believe is more frequently used:

```
trigger ProjectFieldsTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT Name, 
                                    Active__c, 
                                    Funded__c, 
                                    Title__c, 
                                    Project__r.Name, 
                                    Project__r.Active__c, 
                                    Project__r.Awarded__c 
                            FROM    Opportunity 
                            WHERE   Id IN :Trigger.New];

    for(Opportunity o: opp){

        if(o.Project__c != null){

            if(o.Active__c == 'Y'){
                o.Project__r.Active__c = true;
            }
        }
    }
```